# get name generic class in android

Tags: android, generics

how to get name generic class in android ?

```
   public abstract class ServiceBase<T> implements IServiceBase<T> {
    {
       public  ServiceBase(){
             String name="";// need T name . i use  T.class.getName() but is error
             Field f = Entities.class.getDeclaredField(name)
       }
    }
```

I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet. Where I wrong? I really do not know what to do. I wrote all the details above. I've tried and did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

If needed you should provide a `Class<T>` parameter:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<T> implements IServiceBase<T> {
{
   public  ServiceBase(Class<T> clzz){
         String name=clzz.getName();// need T name . i use  T.class.getName() but is error
         Field f = Entities.class.getDeclaredField(name)
   }
}
```